# Optimization in Sci-Py for n >1000

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am doing a constrained optimization using sci-py's optimize tool for 100K observations, but my results are converging to the initial values for n > 1000. That is if I perform optimization on say 500 observations, I get a good local minimum, however as n tends to 1000 the optimized values are the same as the original values:

Here are my objective function and constraints:

Objective function:

```
def objective(x):
    return np.sum(np.array([-TU_array[i]*(NR_fn(x[i])-LS_fn(x[i],pd_array[i])) for i in range(0,len(x))]))

# where
def NR_fn(x):
    R = (1.99525947856706E-13*x**3-0.000000299925*x**2+0.137682384749*x+3648.729074580060)
    return R

def LS_fn(x,pd):
    L =x*pd
    return L
```

and constraints are :

```
def constraint1(x):
    return np.sum(x)-df["creditlimit"].sum()
 
def constraint3(x):
    return np.sum(np.array([LS_fn(x[i],pd_array[i]) for i in range(0,len(x))]))-525000

b = (df["creditlimit"].min(),df["creditlimit"].max())

bnds = (b,)*len(df)

con1 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint1}
# con2 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint2}
con3 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint3}
cons = ([con1,con3])

x0 = np.array(df["creditlimit"])
solution = minimize(objective,x0,method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds,constraints = cons, options={'maxiter': 200, 'disp': True})
x = solution.x
```

Any help on how to go about it? Can I use some other tools which can help minimize my function?

I tried changing the constraints and functional form and expected unique values for my observations but I still got initial values.

Comment: scipy.minimize is not designed for large problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in this case how do I solve the optimization problem?

Comment: I would use a large-scale solver.

Comment: Can you please help with any of such large scale solvers? Can multiple objective optimization help?

Comment: It may be some problem with your data, Inf, some outlier. Also I propose to debug whole minimize function, make sanity checks - take a look if outputs of your functions are valid values. You can compare example that is working well (e.g. n=100) with the one that is not working at all